# Regex for this formula

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I'm struggling with making a regex for this type of formula: LU1O/00054362/8. I'd like to receive only the first part - LU1O every time. It's always letter, letter, number, letter. Please help me with suggestion.

Comment: If it is always 4 characters, why not simply extract the first 4 characters of the input?

Comment: `^[A-Z]{2}[0-9][A-Z]` pattern

Comment: Is it required that letter, letter, number, letter is also followed by other characters as shown in the question?

Comment: If the input can be assumed to be valid: `formula.Substring(0, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   string input = @"LU1O/00054362/8";
   var regex = "^[A-Z]{2}[0-9][A-Z]$";
   var match = Regex.Match(input.Substring(0,4), regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   if (match.Success)
   {
        //matched
   }
```

or

```
  string input2 = @"LU1O/00054362/8";
  var regex2= "^[A-Z]{2}[0-9][A-Z]";
  var match2 = Regex2.Match(input2, regex2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  if (match2.Success)
  {
      //matched
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If '/' is always a delimiter you could string.split('/') and access the first element from the resulting array.